# facebook accountkit out of memory until logout

Tags: android, out-of-memory, account-kit

I am using facebook accountkit (sms) login in my app and it is almost working as intended. There is however one really annoying and critical error.

After login I return to my original activity (I tried with finish() and also just manually pressing back), as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android

However, after I go a few more steps into my application I suddenly get an Out of memory error. It doesn't happen on any specific activity, but happens consistently.

If however, I log in as always, close the app, and open it again. Everything works fine, no Out of memory whatsoever...

The strange thing is that it seems to be a Bitmap that gives the error, but as the app works perfectly fine in all other cases and this only happens (although consistently) when navigating right after login with accountkit.

I have setup my app completely as described in the facebook docs.

Anyone who has experienced this?

Comment: Post some relevant code?

Comment: also stacktrace would help